# RxSwift TestScheduler for two sources

Tags: swift, rx-swift, rxtest

I would like to emit two different signals for two different sources, but I get crash 
`Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)` in `RxSwift/Event.swift` in line 29: `return "next(\(value))"`

this is my simplified code:

```
        let scheduler = TestScheduler(initialClock: 0)

        locationsFactory = TestableLocationsFactory()
        locationsFactory.didReceiveRegion = scheduler.createColdObservable([
        .next(100, regionEvents[0]),
        .next(200, regionEvents[1])
        ]).asObservable()

        locationsFactory.location = scheduler.createColdObservable([
        .next(120, locations[0]),
        .next(220, locations[1])
        ]).asObservable()

        let result = scheduler.createObserver(LocationChange.self)
        let dispatcher = BestAccuracyLocationsDispatcher(persistenceService: persistenceService, apiClient: api, locationManager: locationsFactory)

        subscription = dispatcher.dispatcher.subscribe(result)
        scheduler.start()

        let events = result.events

        XCTAssertEqual(events, [
            .next(120, LocationChange(location: locations[0], trigger: .updateLocations)),
            .next(220, LocationChange(location: locations[1], trigger: .updateLocations)),
        ])
```

When I remove `locationsFactory.didReceiveRegion` or `locationsFactory.location` it works.

Can I create two different scheduler's observables?

Answer (score 0):

I used mock of region `let region = CLRegion()` which is an abstract class. It started to work when I changed it to:

`let region = CLCircularRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 5.555, longitude: 6.666), radius: Double(50), identifier: "xxx")`